# mysqli_escape_string how do i implement it?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a question about my writing to my database:

I'm new to the `mysql_escape_string` because a friend told me.
Since I use `mysql_escape_string` it doesn't write to my db anymore.

Here is the code:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 $iets = $_POST['aantal'] + $_POST['begin'];

 for ($i = $_POST['begin'] ; $i < $iets ; $i++){
     $rows = $rows.'a'.$i.', ';
 }

 $rows = mysql_escape_string(trim($rows, ', '));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 $iets = $_POST['aantal'] + $_POST['begin'];

 for ($i = $_POST['begin'] ; $i < $iets ; $i++){
     $r = 'a'.$i;
    $values = $values.'\''.$_POST[$r].'\', ';
 }

 $values = mysql_escape_string(trim($values, ', '));


$naam = mysql_escape_string($_POST['naam']);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO $naam
(
$rows
)
VALUES 
(
$values
)");
mysql_close($con);


printf("%s<br />%s", $values, $rows);
```

When I have :

```
aantal = 3
begin = 4
```

The output of `printf`, with `a4=abcdef`, `a5=ghijkl`, `a6=mnopq` is:

```
\'abcdef\', \'ghijkl\', \'mnopq\'<br />
a1, a2, a3
```

I don't get it, the backlashes shouldn't have an impact right?

Comment: make `mysql_escape_string` the last thing you do to the values before putting them in the database.

Comment: Anyway, I would recommend you to forget about `mysql_query` and start making use of secure ways such as PDO: http://php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

Comment: You _should not implement_ `mysql_escape_string()`! It is long-since deprecated in favor of [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), which will someday be deprecated in PHP 5.5 as well.

Comment: any good online tutorial of putting data in an DB with PDO or mysqli?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of escaping is to stop characters with special meaning (e.g. `'`) from having that special meaning. Since you are escaping the fragment of SQL containing all your quoted values, you are escaping the quotes and stopping them from quoting the values.

You need to escape *each* value before quoting it.:

```
$values = $values.'\''.$_POST[$r].'\', ';
                     //^^^^^^^^^^ Escape this
```

However:

Don't use `mysql_escape_string` it is broken has been replaced with `mysql_real_escape_string`, but don't even use that, don't use `mysql_*` at all, [it is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068).

Pick a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and use [prepared statements and bound arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) instead of escaping strings and mushing them together into SQL via string concatination.